# Suggestions for open source aspect-oriented library for c#

Tags: c#, open-source, aop

Any suggestions for open source aspect-oriented library for c#. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Post Sharp](http://www.postsharp.org/)

Comment: unfortunately Post Sharp is not FOSS

Answer (score 3):

Spring.NET

Comment: Abandoned by now. Don't waste your time like I did.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Castle Windsor and Dynamic Proxy, which together provide a simple way to apply your standard AOP method interception through external XML configuration.

If you have more advanced AOP needs, [Aspect#](http://www.castleproject.org/aspectsharp/) might be useful (also relies on Dynamic Proxy) - but I have found that Windsor fulfills my needs perfectly.

Please note that Dynamic Proxy provides only runtime AOP. There are solutions out there that can mix in your aspects at compile time (although I can't recall the name of any of them).

Comment: +1 DynamicProxy, but Aspect# is dead

Answer (score 0):

[DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) from CastleProject is probably the most lightweight and powerful solution regarding dynamic interception.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Spring.NET as well, but only because that's the only one I have experience with.  Spring.NET offers so much more (IoC, transaction management, nice validation framework) but you can use just what you need from it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring.NET is great in general, and so is its AOP support.

No idea why people are saying to avoid it. Infact it is one of the most stable and reliable frameworks in the .NET world.

Dev progress is slow, but that is fine because it is already feature rich and stable.