# What Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) libraries for .NET are still actively developed?

Tags: .net, aop

I am trying to find a reasonably mature/stable and freely available (preferably open-source) library for doing AOP in .NET. I've been searching around a bit and found the products below; however, most of them seem dead:

- [**PostSharp**](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) — this is the AOP solution usually recommended for .NET, however it's a commercial product and thus some use restrictions apply. (However, it seems to be sort-of freely available for personal or open-source projects.)
- [**Spring.NET**](http://www.springframework.net/) — not exclusively about AOP, so it's probably too powerful if one only wants to do AOP. (?)
- [**Policy Injection Application Block**](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) — being from Microsoft, I would expect this to be at least maintained.
- [**Castle Windsor**](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) together with [**DynamicProxy**](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) — not primarily an AOP library, but apparently it can be used for that purpose.
- [**Aspect#**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aspectsharp/) — this seems quite dead to me.
- [**Aspect.NET**](http://aspectdotnet.codeplex.com/) — this also seems quite dead to me.
- **NAop** — apparently no longer supported.
- [**AOP.NET**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aopnet/) — this was supposed to be the successor to NAop, and also looks like it died a while ago.

There's probably even more. From the above list I gather that the only real options for doing AOP on .NET is PostSharp (even though it's a commercial product), Spring.NET, Microsoft's Policy Injection Application Block, or perhaps Windsor.

Did I forget any major option?

---

*See also the question [Suggestions for open source aspect-oriented library for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470535/suggestions-for-open-source-aspect-oriented-library-for-c) here on StackOverflow. I posted a new question because I'm specifically interested in the state of development/maintenance of various AOP solutions for .NET.*

Comment: Good question, I'd love to know the latest and greatest on this most interesting topic, that I haven't had a chance to get into. But please, increase the font size of the footnote, even my monitor is squinting.

Comment: This stuff was developed a *long* time ago, .NET is almost 10 years old already.  Avoid confusing *dead* with *done* or "no longer interesting" for FOSS.  It isn't dead if somebody is still paying the hosting fees.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Sorry for being too lax with terminology, I can later edit my question if this seems important. But I would prefer that answers to my question focus on what is active / up-to-date / in widespread use / etc., not on what is dead / obsolete / no longer interesting / whatever.

Comment: Is Spring.NET still actively developed?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: Judging by the [source code repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net)'s [activity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/graphs/contributors), no. The last commit happened in 2016, and the few ones before that in 2015. That's just my impression though, perhaps best to ask the maintainers themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need Windsor to use DynamicProxy. Windsor uses DynamicProxy for its own purposes, just like NHibernate, RhinoMocks, Moq or other libraries/applications/frameworks out there.
If you need just runtime AOP, without IoC container, use  Caste DynamicProxy alone.

It is actively developed, last pre-release was released 2 weeks ago, final release (v2.5) is expected this month.

Note: In previous versions (up to v2.2) DynamicProxy used to live in its own assembly Castle.DynamicProxy.dll. It was later moved to Castle.Core.dll and now no other assembly is required to use it. [Source](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy-Introduction.ashx)

Answer (score 1):

There was also Aurum <strike>(available at [www.machinaaurum.com.br](http://www.machinaaurum.com.br/aspect.html))</strike>, which was built upon Unity. <strike>The source is available on [Codeplex](http://machinaaurum.codeplex.com/).</strike>

Comment: it's not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: Microsoft are releasing a preview of [Interceptors in C#12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#interceptors).