# Open source AOP library for .NET with no interception limitations

Tags: aop

This topic may look like it has been discussed already but I have few more things to say and ask.

The obvious question is; I want to know what AOP library shall I go for a .NET 4.0 enterprise application? As per the post [What Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) libraries for .NET are still actively developed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434183/what-aspect-oriented-programming-aop-libraries-for-net-are-still-actively-dev), one should choose PostSharp or Spring.NET or Microsoft's Policy Injection Application Block. But there are problem with each one.

1. **PostSharp:** This is best but not open. I need one whose source is open.
2. **Spring.NET:** This is too heavy and has limitations like it can intercept only those classes that is not static, must be non-sealed, properties and methods must be virtual, etc...
3. **Microsoft's Policy Injection Application Block:** As per the post [Policy Injection Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664572%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx), this is a legacy component now and may stop being supported by MS and since it is implemented through the Unity interception mechanism hence it has same limitation as that of Spring.NET ([Alternatives to PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/alternatives))

I came across the post [Aspect Oriented Programming: learn step by step and roll your own implementation!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479302/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-learn-step-by-step-and). I have not used it yet but reading through the post gave me an idea that it should serve my purpose. I want to know if anyone has tried it and if it is advised to go for it?

I have one more question to ask; I have used Unity for DI and it is all cool but for AOP, unity is not a good option for my purpose hence I will definitely go for some other tool/library (maybe the one I suggested above!). Is it good to have Unity and something else for AOP in the same application, will there be any problem?

Can anyone please help me here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is an open source tool a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find few good options once you preclude PostSharp and also want to intercept static code.

Some options that you might check out are SheepAspect and Fody, which both take a similar approach to PostSharp (post-compile weaving). Both are very nice and show promise, but are relatively young compared to PostSharp.

Comment: Thank you Mgroves for the reply. I will have a look at your suggestions.