# C# attribute doesnt apply to method

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I have the following C# code

```
 class Program
{
    [My]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }

    [My]
    static void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1111");
    }
}


public class MyAttribute: Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("enter");
    }
    ~MyAttribute()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("leave");
    }

}
```

Attribute **My** applies only to method **Main** (constructor of MyAttribute executes on entering the Main method and destructor executes on leaving them), but not for method **SomeMethod**.

I need feature like this: execute some portion of code (start and kill the process) in some methods, without modifying them (I think, that the attributes may be the best decision).

Please, help

Comment: try changing the messagebox to log to the console instead!

Comment: This is not the intention of attributes.

Comment: try looking up AOP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434183/what-aspect-oriented-programming-aop-libraries-for-net-are-still-actively-dev

Comment: What you want to do isn't what attributes can do (at least not by itself). An attribute is just a tag to mark a method/class/property. What you do with it after that is up to you but it generally involves using reflection or 3rd party libarary to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: `CodeAccessSecurity` attribute can do what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the attributes in the correct way:

Attributes should indicate a property of a class or a class member and in most of the cases are used by the consumer of the object.

Very often attributes are used with reflection to get information:

```
System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(t);
```